# Counting number of pixels/cells with particular value in raster using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, raster

I have a raster image containing values ranging from 1 to 10 in Integer format.

I want to count the number of pixel with value = 1.

Is there any method in Arcpy which returns the pixel count if given raster and value as input?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [Build Raster Attribute Table](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/build-raster-attribute-table.htm) tool, then a [SearchCursor](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/analyze/arcpy-data-access/searchcursor-class.htm).

```
values = {}
arcpy.BuildRasterAttributeTable_management(your_raster, "Overwrite")
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(your_raster, ['VALUE', 'COUNT']) as rows:
    for row in rows:
        values[row[0]] = row[1]
print values.get(12345, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks, @Luke was I was struggling with numpy I got the answer but it took a lot of time!. This is simple and faster. Thank you once again.